# How to change file index outside the root

Tags: angular-cli

When I run `ng-build`, it export the file index.html and js.. onside folder dist.
I want to move file index.html to outside folder dist and edit link

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/inline.bundle.js"></script>
```

but it can not found file images, .woff...
I try edit the base href="dist/" but when run app the domain is localhost/dist/index.html I don't want this.
So how I can change index.html outside root when `ng-build` that can still be found?